# Old Facebook account formats - Retrieve account details

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that retrievs the education and work details from FB while the user is loging in to my system using his FB account.

The problem is that 'old FB account IDs' has another format than the most recent FB account IDs. When a user logs into my application with old FB account the education and work details are only partly retrieved. It seems like the transfer of data is interrupted somehow. This does not happen while login in with the newest account id format.

Format of old FB account ID 698392510
Format of new FB account ID 100001470546089

Does anyone know why this might happen?
Here is the code:`code $fb_schools = array();
            for ( $i = 0; $i <= count($fbme['education']); $i++ ) {
                $educ = $fbme['education'][$i];
                if (strlen(utf8_decode(trim($educ['school']['name'])))>0){
                $fb_schools[] = utf8_decode(trim($educ['school']['name']));
                }
                if ($educ['year']) {
                    $educDetails = array(
                        'username' => trim($fbme['id']),
                        'password' => trim($fbme['id']),
                        'schoolname' => utf8_decode(trim($educ['school']['name'])),
                        'year' => trim($educ['year']['name']),
                        'type' => trim($educ['type'])
                    );
                } else {
                    $educDetails = array(
                        'username' => trim($fbme['id']),
                        'password' => trim($fbme['id']),
                        'schoolname' => utf8_decode(trim($educ['school']['name'])),
                        'type' => trim($educ['type'])
                    );
                }`

Comment: What do you mean with only partly retrieved? What API call are you doing?

Comment: And what do you mean with partly retrieved?

Comment: By that I mean that only 2 or 3 records of the total records are fetched from the users education and work experience details. If the user has 10 records associated with his account, only 2 or 3 of them are retrievef